Can a property be followed by []?
I am studying this C# code from .NET documentation and I don't understand the following snippet (it is under the title "Examine the implementation"):
var issueAndPRQuery = new GraphQLRequest
{
 Query = queryText
};
issueAndPRQuery.Variables["repo_name"] = repoName;

I don't understand the syntax Variables["repo_name"].
Variables is a property of the object and I don't understand why the [] are used.
I don't know much about GraphQL but I found this code which should give some light.
As you can see, in line 46 of GraphQLRequest class, Variables property is declared:
public object? Variables
{
    get => TryGetValue(VARIABLES_KEY, out object value) ? value : null;
    set => this[VARIABLES_KEY] = value;
}

Any insights?

Variables is apparently an indexed property, indexed by a string value. See also Named indexed property in C#?

You have a Dictionary and the code is looking up the value of KEY = "repo_name"

The example from the documentation uses its own GraphQLRequest class (see snippet linked from the docs) which is:
public class GraphQLRequest
{
    [JsonProperty("query")]
    public string? Query { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("variables")]
    public IDictionary<string, object> Variables { get; } = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    public string ToJsonText() =>
        JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
}

As you can see Variables is of type IDictionary<string,object> and not object, so you can use the graphQlRequest.Variables[key] as you would on any other dictionary to get the value for a key.
